# Handle ASP.NET Web Form postbacks in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, postback, webforms

I am trying to modernize an existing web application that was built using ASP.NET Web Forms. I'm trying to that by wrapping it inside MVC 3 (Razor) and using the views from there. What I have been doing so far is to use Server.Execute method in order to get HTML content that I can return as HTML and render inside the View in MVC 3. It executes an .aspx file like this:

```
var writer = new StringWriter();
ctx.Server.Execute("~/" + aspxPath, writer, true);
string html = writer.ToString();
```

In order to route everything via MVC 3 I had to set the RouteExistingFiles property to true:

```
RouteTable.Routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
```

This is all good until I must handle postbacks from forms. Postbacks work if I don't set the RouteExistingFiles property, but then only the body content part is shown since it bypasses the MVC 3 routing. As you can see above I tried to set "preserveForm" to true when calling the Execute method, but to no help. Is there any way to handle postbacks in MVC 3 that originates from a regular form in ASP.NET Web Forms? And is there any other way (totally different maybe) to try and solve my problem when I want to reuse many .aspx files and present them another way in MVC 3?

Comment: Seeing as you aren't converting the templates to MVC or leveraging MVC in your port, why not just leave the forms based pages side-by-side with any new MVC razor code. If you decide to convert them, port them properly.

Comment: For anyone interested, I ended up using common header, menu and footer .html-files and rendering them side by side with the content. This is done differently for .aspx pages and new Razor pages but yields the same layout, feel and look - and it works perfectly.